# Mixing String and int in Java

Tags: java

I am used to debug by printing Log message. The variables I keep track of consists of String and int.
For example, I used to print something like:

```
Log.e(TAG, value1+":"+value2+":"+String3+":"+String4+":"+value5);
Log.e(TAG, String6+":"+value7);
```

where `value1` etc. are `int`, `String3` etc. are `String` variables.

Now my question is, can I write a method that takes **arbitrary** collection of variables (int, String or other primitive types) as parameters, and output the Log?
For `String` I can use `method(String... arg)`, but I don't know how to do that with `int`.
I tried `(Object...)` and put `.toString()` everywhere, but `int` is not of type `Object`....

Edit:
My ultimate goal: I want a method that only takes the variable I want to debug as parameters. (They can be any types, not just String or int... just any type you can convert to string). So this method has to do the conversion of primitive->Object for me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not a problem, you can cast `int` to `Integer` that is an object

java is doing it by default, you can send int to a method that receives an `Object`
its called [AutoBoxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

the automatic convertions:

[image]

```
public static String toS(Object o1, Object o2){
    return o1 + " " + o2;
}
```

and now you can send an integer to it, it will convert it to Integer automatically :

```
int i = 8;
String combined = toS(i, "hello");
```

Comment: Problem is, they can be any primitive type, may be boolean or char. I don't want to do the conversion everytime I print log, I want a method that do this automatically for me, so that my method only takes parameters I need to debug

Comment: @Ivan Any primitive type will be auto-boxed into its corresponding wrapper type.

Comment: `boolean` will be converted to `Boolean` automatically.

Comment: I see... so what I did wrong is putting .toString()... I shouldn't put that in my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard java logger, you can do:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}", new Object[]{1, 2, "StringA", "StringB", 3 });
```

If you just want to resolve the String, you can use the `java.text.Messageformat`:

```
MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}", 1, 2, "StringA", "StringB", 3 );
```

If you do not want to use varargs syntax and have a plain object array, you can still use the `MessageFormat` and write:

```
Object[] args = new Object[]{ 1, 2, "StringA", "StringB", 3};
MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}", args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Object type in varargs. For ex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        display(1, "test", 9.5);
    }

    static void display(Object... values) {
        for (Object object : values) {
            System.out.println(" object value " + object.toString());//Log here
        }
    }
```

Which prints output as

```
 object value 1
 object value test
 object value 9.5
```

That takes primitives and Objects both. In case of primitives autoboxing happens and it allows you to do so.

Comment: A `null` check would be nice too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Wrapper classes for primitives, then you can call toString() on them.

e.g.:

```
 Integer myInteger = new Integer(5);
 System.out.println(myInteger.toString());
```

would print

```
 5
```